# C# ImageProcessor.ImageFactory does not reduce PNG image file size, working for JPG

Tags: c#

Bellow code is reducing size of jpeg but its not working for png.

I have also added **preserveExifData: true** in constructor.

```
byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(strfilePath);
int quality = 25;

using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(preserveExifData: true))
{
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ImageProcessor.ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageProcessor.ImageFactory(true,true))
        {
            imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .Quality(quality)
                        .Save(outStream);
        }
        FileStream file = new FileStream(processedFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        outStream.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: PNG is a lossless image file format. While there are things you can do to reduce the file size, you can't just reduce the quality of the output by tweaking some parameter, as you can with jpeg.

Comment: @canton7 What else I can do to reduce size? but Image dimensions need to be same. I can not resize image.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500469/i-have-to-compress-the-png-file-image-without-losing-the-quality